# Site thumbnail will not change

Tags: sharepoint-online, thumbnail

I have a site that for some reason I cannot change the thumbnail from the default image. I have tried multiple things but no matter what - when I go back in to edit it has defaulted back to the default image.

I have other sites that were built from the same template and do not have this issue. It's not urgent but I would really like to know if anyone has any ideas on what is causing this?

Comment: Are you trying to change site logo thumbnail?

Comment: yes I am Ganesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-site-logo-keeps-changing-to-default/549ca26f-eb29-4211-b44f-6d6350836ea0

Save your logo image file locally as the following filename: `__SiteIcon__.png` (there are two '_' before and after the name.)
Copy/upload/drag-drop the file into "Site Contents/Site Assets" - overwriting the existing one if it exists.
QUICKLY "check-out" the file you copied, so the system can't overwrite it with the default.
Refresh the cache on you browser and the logo should be correct.